# httpurlconnection which stream should be closed?

Tags: java, http-post, httpurlconnection

Below is my httppost client using httpurlconnection in java. I have seen a few sample code in internet and they do not close outputstream after flush() but they do it for input stream. When I try for ordinary scenarios it seem to be working in any case.(may be since I am closing http connection every time.) What is the best practice for this, should I close outputstream, inputstream or just connection is enough ? And what if we decide to use keepalive ? Does it change anything with respect to this question.

```
    public CBBag executePost(byte[] input) throws CBException {
    InputStream is = null;
    DataOutputStream wr =null;
    int STATE = 0;
    try{
        // Create connection
        setCommonConnectionParameters(input.length);

        // Send request
        wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(input);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();//should I call  ?
        //Get response          
        STATE = 1;
        is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,encoding));
        String line = rd.readLine() ;
        while (line != null ) {
            response.append(line);
            line = rd.readLine();
        }
        rd.close();//should I call ?
        return handleResponse(response);
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {
        closeQuietly(is,wr);
        throw handleException(STATE, e);
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```